# Templating plugin Pure.js causes infinite loop IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, template-engine

I am using pure.js 1.29 (PURE Unobtrusive Rendering Engine for HTML) as the js Templating language for my sorting / pagination / filtering. For some reason, IE 9 crashes when I try the page. IE 7, 8, FF, Chrome all render properly.

Answer (score 0):

Its causing an infinite loop in IE 9. line 362 of pure.js :

```
ie = attValue.match(/#\{[^\}]*\}/);
if (!ie && attValue !== '') {attValues.push(attValue);}}}
```

ie is returning 'undefined' causing the loop. so replace with below:

```
if (typeof ie.lastIndex == 'undefined'){
ie = false;}else{
ie = attValue.match(/#\[^\}]*\}/);}
if (!ie && attValue !== '') {attValues.push(attValue);}}}
```